# .NET Core web API change default port (5000)

Tags: linux, deployment, .net-core

I have two applications in .NET Core 2.2. I need to host both on Centos7. One of them works correctly, on port 5000. I'm trying run second and i have a problem with change of port 5000 to another. In Program.cs i changed:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5200")
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

But it doesnt work. 
I run aplication by service. Its my configuration

```
    [Unit]
    Description=ASP.Net Project

    [Service]
    WorkingDirectory=/home/piotrekb3/etc/slotsapi
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/piotrekb3/etc/slotsapi/Slots.WebApi.dll
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=10
    SyslogIdentifier=SlotsApi
    User=piotrekb3
    Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I run by command:

```
systemctl start slotsapi.service
```

I tried also change in lanuchSettings.json:

```
"Slots.WebApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5003;http://localhost:5004",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

But nothing.
Any idea how can i resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is correct, however you can add the port to a configuration file. If you want to deploy it behind NGINX you need to specify both HTTP and HTTPS I guess.

This is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static IConfiguration configuration;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);

        configuration = builder.Build();

        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                // Set properties and call methods on options
            })
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls($"http://localhost:{configuration["Port"]};https://localhost:{Convert.ToInt32(configuration["Port"])+1}")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

This site is hosted by Kestrel using this approach:
https://www.multilabs.org

Don't forget to add a configuration to your appsettings.json: "Port":5200